# MacBook Pro (macOS 10.15.1) waking up from sleep ... with Reminders from iOS?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, catalina, reminders

the weirdest thing is happening and I can reproduce it quite reliably.

I put my Mac to sleep by closing the lid and check it has gone to sleep in the evening.
In the morning, both my iPhone and iPad go out of Sleep Mode at 8am so all previous Reminders & notifications fire up then. I happened to be next to my desk with my iPhone in hand and I noticed the Mac waking up. It is very quiet so I went near and heard the fans being active...

I used the Consolation3 app from H. Oakley to browse the log entries and the Mac is indeed asleep before 8:00am but suddenly wakes up some seconds later. 
A lot of entries about remindersd, fetching CoreData, CalDav ...

I have not yet upgraded to the new Reminders because of shared lists with family members but if that is the (proven) reason (not just something Apple would say to do to try things out because there is no way back) I will upgrade.

Do not disturb is active until 7am, but the Mac awakes at 8am.
PowerNap is not enabled.

Does anyone know what is happening here?
Is there any other check I could/should perform?

Thank you

Logs:
1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/92wx69sx5lhy21v/20191119_eventMessage%20CONTAINS%5Bc%5D%20reminders.rtf?dl=0
2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5np7ccl5sn6ccb/20191119_eventMessage%20CONTAINS%5Bc%5D%20sleep.rtf?dl=0
3. https://www.dropbox.com/s/j475scc2nmfvuql/20191119_eventMessage%20CONTAINS%5Bc%5D%20darkwake.rtf?dl=0
4. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh87y7bep3dor86/20191119_eventMessage%20CONTAINS%5Bc%5D%20cause.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Power nap is already disabled. Don’t trust my network connection enough to install updates autonomously. I don’t know what DnD is (apart from Dungeons & Dragons!!)

Comment: Do not disturb is active on this Mac between 2230 and 0700, while on iPhone is active between 2230 and 0800. Do you think this is correlated? I think if the Mac is sleeping it should just not turn on unless I do it. The log says some kind of notification woke it up, possibly from Reminders

Comment: Done! Added four links to filtered out logs. They span over one minute from 8:00 to 8:01 am, before that the Mac was correctly sleeping. I filtered out "sleep" "cause" "darkwake" and "reminders"

Comment: It happened again this morning: iCloud reminder wakes up the Mac, which then goes back to sleep as this time I didn’t have Sibelius running before closing the lid.